# Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081 every single time

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, daemon, bitcoin

I'm running Windows 10 so I can't use any Linux commands which everything I've looked up has when faced with this issue. I've uninstalled and reinstalled it a few times, I've turned off my antivirus and it still doesn't connect. The blockchain finishes then it just restarts again in a loop. I cannot find a way to fix this.

Comment: In windows start monerod.exe by right click START AS ADMINISTRATOR

Answer (score 1):

This means either the daemon is not running on your machine or VM, or is running on a different port, or your OS is preventing the connection.

To check the first case: look at your list of processes (some equivalent of the ps utility)

To check the second case: look at the list of listening processes (some equivalent of the netstat or ss utilies)

If you do find a monerod listening on 18081 in the steps above, then it's your OS preventing the connection. A fix for this, though probably not the only one, is to change OS (and not only for that reason).

Comment: It's running on 23 different ports according to cport, is it supposed to do this? I decided to run monero-daemon.bat and it appears to be working. It's about 54% through and says it'll take 1 day. Is it usually this long or is there still a problem? The only other OS I use is Kali Linux.

Comment: It's plausible. As long as it's listening on port 18081, that's what you want. It'll also be connected to other peers on the Monero network, from where it gets the chain. A couple days looks like a plausible time to get the chain. SSDs on beefy hardware should get it in less than a day, slow spinning hard drives can take a week.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the `confirm-external-bind=1` option to the monerod.conf file which had fixed the error.